# Error while trying to run Jupyter Notebook in a newly created environment

Tags: jupyter-notebook, conda

```
INTEL MKL ERROR: dlopen(/Users/bea/sample_project/env/lib/libmkl_core.1.dylib, 9): no suitable image found.  Did find:
    /Users/bea/sample_project/env/lib/libmkl_core.1.dylib: code signature invalid for '/Users/bea/sample_project/env/lib/libmkl_core.1.dylib'
.
Intel MKL FATAL ERROR: Cannot load libmkl_core.1.dylib.
```

I don't understand the error

Answer (score 0):

```
python -m pip install jupyter
```

I did this inside my Anaconda (which I shouldn't have to do) and it installed jupyter... fixed the issue for me.

Comment: Hmm didn't change anything. Jupyter is installed I don't think thats the issue. Thanks tho.